# Bounds on error correcting codes

Tags: coding-theory

So I was reading 'Introduction to Coding Theory' by van Lint and in the chapter regarding bounds on codes, he has defined a quantity $A(n,d)$=max {$M$ |an $(n,M,d)$ code exists} ( $M$  is the number of codewords) and all the calculations are done with this quantity. My question is, why not do it on $M$ directly instead?

Comment: It's not totally clear to me what you're asking, but certainly it's helpful that $A(n,d)$ is a constant number depending in n and d, whereas M is a quantity that is basically a dummy variable in the construction of a set you use to define A.

Comment: What do you mean by "do in on M directly"?

Comment: Instead of finding the bounds for M, the book has found bounds for max{M}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic goal of designing a code is efficiency, so given $n,d$ the basic goal is to maximize $M$ so we can send as many messages as possible for a given performance level defined by a given blocklength and a given minimum distance.

Also, extremal codes give rise to some beautiful algebra and combinatorics, e.g., the Golay codes.